# Sum the grouping total individually for Report items

Tags: reporting-services, aggregate, ssrs-2012, ssrs-grouping

[image]I have a report item which is based on a calculation from 2 different entities. 
I am trying to group the report based on the product number.But I am not able to get the total for each group. But found a way to get the grand total from the report using the following code.
I want to find a way to aggregate the total for each product and set it to zero when it moves to the next product.

Already tried: Creating a separated calculated field to the data-set but as it is from from 2 different data sets so I am not able to create a calculated field.
Tried referencing the aggregate elsewhere in the report and tried to reference it, did not work.

```
Public totalReplacement as Integer
Public totalGSF as Integer

Public Function AddTotalReplacement(ByVal replacement AS Integer )
totalReplacement = totalReplacement + replacement
End Function

Public Function AddTotalGSF(ByVal thisGSF AS integer)
totalGSF = totalGSF + thisGSF
End Function

Public Function GetTotalReplacement()
return totalReplacement
End Function

Public Function GetTotalGSF()
return totalGSF
End Function
```

The above code keeps adding the total of each product with the before total. But I wish to the make the total replacement zero when it move to the next product.

Comment: would help if you show what you are getting now as an image and what your desired result is in a mock up of some sort.. Usually if you just group by the product you can get a sub total per group and a grand total at the end.. show the layout / design view.. might help

Comment: @Harry I have added the output screenshot which I am getting now. In the Column AB - you can see that its adding all the **Created_issued to Field Qty** (AA) for particular product number in A. 
for the product 10000182 you can see 3 and 8 quantities in the AA column but I am trying to use the code to calculate the sum of that particular product it returns as 33. It's adding 22+11, but I wish to see only 11.

Answer (score 0):

Alright Do something like Below

1. Switch to Design view.
2. Right-click the data region cell that contains the field
   [Created_issued to Field Qty (AA)], and click Add Total.
3. This adds a row with a sum of the dollar amount for each order.

Try this and it shall give you 11 as Result. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Created_issued to Field Qty does not allow me to do that as it is a reportitem. It is based on calculations from 2 different data-sets. 
I was able to do that in the **Vendor Qty(X)** and **Received Qty(Y)**, it is also calculated field but from the same data-set.